# UTC DateTime Parsing missmatch in Time

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert this string `Mon Aug 05 08:02:27 +0000 2013` to `DateTime` and it is not converting time properly. There is some variations in time. Whats the problem here ? I use the below code

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Aug 05 08:02:27 +0000 2013","ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The output it is returning is

```
{05-08-2013 13:32:27}
Date: {05-08-2013 00:00:00}
Day: 5
DayOfWeek: Monday
DayOfYear: 217
Hour: 13
Kind: Local
Millisecond: 0
Minute: 32
Month: 8
Second: 27
Ticks: 635113063470000000
TimeOfDay: {13:32:27}
Year: 2013
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` is quite confusing (broken?) wrt. time zones and such.

A quick solution to you might be `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`, that is:

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Aug 05 08:02:27 +0000 2013",
  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
  );
```

Without any `DateTimeStyles`, the default is to return a `DateTime` of "kind" `Local`, as you see in the output you're quoting. Since your input string explicitly has `+0000` on the `zzz` position, and your local time is distinct from `+0000` on your computer, the default is to convert to your time.

With `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`, the "kind" of the returned value is `Utc`.

For a possibly less confusing date and time interface, consider [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).

Comment: Thanks for link to Noda Time - was unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The ParseExact method returns DateTime as Local time, and you specified that the input string is UTC. The time shift results from your time zone. If you convert the resulting DateTime back to UTC you should get the time exactly as in your input string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

To get UTC time directly use this overload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx

and pass DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal as last argument.

Comment: While getting the value itself how to get that as actual UTC Time? Any idea?